# How to enable lftp protocol logging?

Tags: linux, lftp

We are trying to get lftp to log all its protocol commands (during the login).  I see several verbose options in the man page but the all have to do with a specific command issued after logging in (like: queue, or mirror).

Is there a way to enabled protocol level logging in `lftp` simular to that of `ssh -v ...`?

Answer (score 13):

Append `debug` to `lftp`'s configuration file:

`echo debug>>~/.lftp/rc`

This is the likely place for your local lftp configuration file.

Comment: works great. also can go in /etc/lftp.conf

Comment: Just a note. When `debug` is added to the `~/.lftp/rc` all transfers get "silently" logged to the `~/.lftp/transfer_log` file.